# Questions regarding the following quote: "There's one piece of television program that I will never forget"

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-structure

Here's a context:

> Q: what was the most memorable episode of a TV show you've watched?
>
> A: There's one piece of television program that I will never forget. It was....

In this situation, it is the piece(episode) of the TV show, not the television program itself.

Therefore, I think this should be transformed into:

> 1. There's one piece that I will never forget of television program.
> 2. There's one piece of television program, which I will never forget.

Questions:

1. Here, is ***piece*** referring to a scene or episode?
2. Why is it that 'a' is not used right before 'television program'?
3. Is there any difference between television program and TV show?

Comment: It's not clear whether a scene or an episode is meant. Probably "a" was not used because the speaker wasn't a native speaker and was not speaking English fluently.

Comment: *piece of television program* is not idiomatic.  We would say "show" or "episode".   But we could say, in a different context, "That ten-minute scene was a great piece of TV programming".  Just as we would say "a tasty slice of melon" and not "a tasty slice of *a* melon" or "a pocketful of sunshine".

Comment: @TR - "show," "episode," or perhaps "scene", if it's a smaller segment of the program.